# RabbitMQ: Delay exchange not delivered to queue

Tags: rabbitmq

I enabled message delayed plugin in RabbitMQ (plugin is available in https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange). Delayed-message exchange (named "delayed-exchange") was created in Exchanged menu . When I try to send message to "delayed-exchange" by piece of code:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("delayed-exchange", queueName, Utils.toJson(obj),
  message -> {
     message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(priorityCode);
     message.getMessageProperties().setDelay(delay);
     message.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
     return message;
  });
```

I can see the message appear in the management console in the "Message Rates" chart:
[Exchange message rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1gez.png)

But there is no message deliverd to queue:
[Queue message rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9684H.png)

Have any idea for me ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what library it is, so I can't check, but I'm willing to bet that you've misunderstood the arguments to the `convertAndSend` function:

```
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("delayed-exchange", queueName, ...
```

When you're publishing to an exchange, you specify a "routing key", and how that is interpreted is up to the exchange. Other than the special "default exchange" whose name is the empty string, this is *not* a queue name.

How the routing key works depends on the exchange type, which in the case of the `delayed-exchange` plugin [depends on the special `x-delayed-type` option](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange#routing) when setting up the exchange:

- If it's a "fanout" exchange, the routing key is ignored, and messages are published to all bound queues
- If it's a "direct" exchange, the routing key is matched directly against the binding key
- If it's a "topic" exchange, the routing key can be matched against patterns of routing keys
- Other types of exchange are available to do more exotic routing

In all cases, you need to create a "binding" between the exchange and the queue, and from your screenshot we can see you haven't done this:

[image: Message showing "No Bindings"]

You need to choose an exchange type, create an appropriate binding, and use the relevant routing key - just as you would without the delayed exchange.